# How to control the Bibliography numbered and author year in single command

Tags: bibliographies

I am using natbib package. I would like to control bib style in single command `\numberedref`.

My requirement is if the `\numberedref` command is available in the tex file the output is shown in *numbered reference list* all citation link should be appeared in numbered. If the command is not available by default, author year reference should be shown. This will  happen *without changing the reference list items like `\bibitem[Sabatinis et al., 1999]{Sabatini:1999}`*

But I don't know the idea  *how to control the user defined single command `\numberedref`*

My tex file below mentioned:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.70}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{\color{gray},}{,}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=gray}

\def\@editor{}
\def\editor#1{%
     \gdef\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}



\def\@reviewer{}
\def\reviewer#1{%
     \gdef\@reviewer{\raggedright \textbf{Reviewed by:}\newline #1}}

\def\@metanote{}
\def\metanote#1{%
     \gdef\@metanote{\raggedright  #1}}

\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@abstract{}
\def\abstract#1{%
     \gdef\@abstract{\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\selectfont #1}}

\def\@keywords{}
\def\keywords#1{%
     \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}}

\def\@firstpara{}
\def\firstpara#1{%
     \gdef\@firstpara{\raggedright  #1}}

\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
linecolor=black,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
theoremseparator={~|},%
frametitlerule=false,%
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=white, right color=black}}},
frametitlerulecolor=black,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=6pt,
innerbottommargin=6pt,
innerleftmargin=6pt,
innerrightmargin=6pt,
frametitlebelowskip=0pt,
}



\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{keybox}{KEY CONCEPT}

\begin{document}


\theendnotes

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{Keith Lindsey is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology.}
\abstract{Plants are sessile organisms and therefore they must adapt their growth and architecture to a changing environment.}
\metanote{$\dagger$Joint corresponding authors}
\keywords{root development, POLARIS peptide, hormonal crosstalk, osmotic stress, kinetic modelin}
\firstpara{\section*{Introduction}
Hormone signaling systems coordinate plant \hfilneg}
\maketitle




Patterning in Arabidopsis root development is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the root tip (\citealp{Sabatini:1999}), requiring the regulated expression of speciÞc genes. This auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be sink-driven (\citealp{Friml:2002}) and com- putational modeling suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis in the root. 

\clearpage


\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem[Sabatinis et al., 1999]{Sabatini:1999}Sabatini, S., Sabatini, S., Beis, D., Wolkenfelt, H., Murfett, J., Guilfoyle, T., et al. (1999). An auxin-dependent distal organizer of pattern and polarity in the Arabidopsis root. Cell 99, 463--472. doi: 10.1016/S0092-8674(00)81535-4
\bibitem[Friml et al., 2002]{Friml:2002}Friml, J., Benkova, E., Blilou, I., Wisniewska, J., Hamann, T., Ljung, K., et al. (2002). AtPIN4 mediates sink-driven auxin gradients and root patterning in Arabidopsis. Cell 108, 661--673. doi: 10.1016/S0092-8674(02)00656-6
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: Change author year to numbered bib]

Comment: This sounds like a job for `biblatex` and its `\autocite` feature.

Comment: Please provide the sample for this. I don't know how to implement the above logic

Comment: I am unable to change the \citealp{} and thebibliography environment. Any logic is there

Comment: You seem to define a userinterface for authors to publish in a journal. Package `biblatex` provides package options in kay-value syntax. You can choose the style of citations to be `numeric`(which is the default) or `authoryear`. `biblatex` works best in conjunction with biber, a modern alternative to classic bibtex. <- If the bibliographical data is stored in an accompanying database. I switched to `biblatex` a while ago, so i am a bit rusty with natbib.

Comment: I think with natbib, the style of citations is controlled by a package option as well. Can you add to the question, what you mean by changing `citealp` and `thebibliography`?